# How can I know the length of sublists in an expression without evaluating the expression?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list called `eaData` which contains sublists of the form `{a, b, number}`, where each sublist gives the number of steps in the Euclidean algorithm (EA) for numbers $a$ and $b$.

I have the following code:

```
eaSteps[{a_, b_}] :=
  NestWhileList[{#[[2]], Mod[#[[1]], #[[2]]]}&, {a, b}, #[[2]] != 0 &]
```

So for example

```
eaSteps[{1736, 1333}]
```

> ```
> {{1736,1333},{1333,403},{403,124},{124,31},{31,0}}`
> ```

I also have

```
eaData = 
   SortBy[
     Flatten[
       Table[
         {a, b, Length[eaSteps[{a, b}]] - 1},
         {a, 1, 100},
         {b, 1, a}],
       1],
     Part[#,3]&]
```

My question is: Given that my `eaData` list contains 5050 sublists, how could I know there are 5050 subentries before I even run the code?

I know that for the EA, the maximum number of steps is at most 5 times the minimum number of digits of either a or b, but how does that help me here?

Further, if `b <= a <= 1000`, then how can I find the `a` and `b` values that require the most steps in the EA?

I'm thinking that I know `a` has at most 4 digits, so there are at most 20, steps. But now I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: shouldn't you change `{a, 1, 25}` to `{a, 1, 100}` to get 5050 sublists?

Comment: yes sorry, I meant {a,1,100}, i just mean, how do I know without running the code itself that I'd get 5050. what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2:** The  functions `maxEALengthPair` and `maxEALength` can be replaced with alternatives without loops using `InverseFunction[Fibonacci]`:

```
ClearAll[fibonacciFloor, maxEALengthPair2, maxEALength2]
fibonacciFloor[n_] := Floor[InverseFunction[Fibonacci][n]]
maxEALength2[n_] := fibonacciFloor[n] - 2
maxEALengthPair2[n_] := Fibonacci[fibonacciFloor[n] + {0, -1}]
And @@ (maxEALengthPair2 @ # == maxEALengthPair @ # & /@ 
  {50, 100, 500, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10^7, 10^9})
```

> True

```
And @@ (maxEALength2@# == maxEALength@# & /@
   {50, 100, 500, 1000,  10000, 100000, 1000000, 10^7, 10^9})
```

> True

***Conjecture:*** For any `n` such that  `Fibonacci[k] <= n <= Fibonacci[k+1]`, the length of longest list `eaSteps[{a, b}]` (`b<a<=n`)  is `k-2` and is reached by the pair `{a, b} = Fibonacci[{k, k-1}]`.

**Update:** It is also possible to find a pair of numbers `{a, b}` less than `n` with maximum length for the sequence `eaSteps[{a,b}]` without "running the code". It seems that  `Fibonacci` sequence can be used to identify a pair with maximum  `eaSteps` length (I have no idea why though):

First, consecutive triples of the Fibonacci sequence satisfy the relation implicit in `eaSteps`:

```
And @@ (# == Mod[#3, #2] & @@@ Partition[Fibonacci[Range[2, 10^5]], 3, 1])
```

> True

Also, if we start with a consecutive `Fibonacci` numbers `{a, b}`, `eaSteps` traces all the  Fibonacci numbers smaller than `b`:

```
Reverse@eaSteps[Fibonacci[{101, 100}]][[All, 1]] == Fibonacci[Range[2, 101]]
```

> True

```
ClearAll[maxEALengthPair, maxEALength]
maxEALengthPair[n_] := Module[{i = 0}, 
   While[Fibonacci[++i] < n]; Fibonacci[{i - 1, i - 2}]];
maxEALength[n_] := Module[{i = 0}, While[Fibonacci[++i] < n]; i - 3]

TeXForm @ Grid[{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ Transpose[{{"n",  "pair"},
 {#, maxEALengthPair /@ #} &@{50, 100, 500, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10^7}}], 
   Dividers -> All]
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{n} & 50 & 100 & 500 & 1000 & 10000 & 100000 & 1000000 & 10000000 \\
> \hline
>  \text{pair} & \{34,21\} & \{89,55\} & \{377,233\} & \{987,610\} & \{6765,4181\} & \{75025,46368\} & \{832040,514229\} &
>    \{9227465,5702887\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Brute-force approach gives the same results for `n ∈ {50, 100, 500, 1000}`:

```
nl = {50, 100, 500, 1000} ;
{#, MaximalBy[Reverse /@ Subsets[Range[#], {2}], Length @* eaSteps][[1]] & /@ #}&@nl
Grid[{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ Transpose[{{"n",  "pair"}, {#, 
   MaximalBy[Reverse /@ Subsets[Range[#], {2}], Length[eaSteps[#]] &][[1]] & /@ #} &@nl}], 
  Dividers -> All]
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{n} & 50 & 100 & 500 & 1000 \\
> \hline
>  \text{pair} & \{34,21\} & \{89,55\} & \{377,233\} & \{987,610\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Note: For some `n`, there are multiple pairs with maximum `eaSteps` length. For example, for `n=50` there are 7 pairs that give a length 7 list:

```
MaximalBy[Reverse /@ Subsets[Range[50], {2}], Length @* eaSteps ]
```

> {{34, 21}, {47, 29}, {50, 29}, {49, 30}, {49, 31}, {50, 31}, {47, 
>     34}}

```
 Length[eaSteps @ #] - 1 &/@ %
```

> {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}

The table above gives only the first of multiple pairs.

We next tabulate the pairs and lengths for some `Fibonacci` numbers:

```
Grid[{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ Transpose[{{"k", "F[k]", "pair", "length"}, 
 {#, Fibonacci@#, Column[maxEALengthPair@Fibonacci@#] & /@ #, 
  maxEALength[Fibonacci@#] & /@ #} & @ Range[10, 60, 5]}], 
  Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{k} & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 & 40 & 45 & 50 & 55 & 60 \\
> \hline
>  \text{F[k]} & 55 & 610 & 6765 & 75025 & 832040 & 9227465 & 102334155 & 1134903170 & 12586269025 & 139583862445 & 1548008755920 \\
> \hline
>  \text{pair} & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  34 \\
>  21 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  377 \\
>  233 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  4181 \\
>  2584 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  46368 \\
>  28657 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  514229 \\
>  317811 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  5702887 \\
>  3524578 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  63245986 \\
>  39088169 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  701408733 \\
>  433494437 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  7778742049 \\
>  4807526976 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  86267571272 \\
>  53316291173 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  956722026041 \\
>  591286729879 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \hline
>  \text{length} & 7 & 12 & 17 & 22 & 27 & 32 & 37 & 42 & 47 & 52 & 57 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

```
Grid[{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ Transpose[{{"k", "F[k]", "pair", "length"}, 
 {#, Fibonacci@#, Column[maxEALengthPair@Fibonacci@#] & /@ #, 
  maxEALength[Fibonacci@#] & /@ #} &@Range[4, 25]}], 
  Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{k} & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\
> \hline
>  \text{F[k]} & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89 & 144 & 233 & 377 & 610 & 987 & 1597 & 2584 & 4181 & 6765 \\
> \hline
>  \text{pair} & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  2 \\
>  1 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  3 \\
>  2 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  5 \\
>  3 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  8 \\
>  5 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  13 \\
>  8 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  21 \\
>  13 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  34 \\
>  21 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  55 \\
>  34 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  89 \\
>  55 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  144 \\
>  89 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  233 \\
>  144 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  377 \\
>  233 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  610 \\
>  377 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  987 \\
>  610 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  1597 \\
>  987 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  2584 \\
>  1597 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  4181 \\
>  2584 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \hline
>  \text{length} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

**Original answer:**

You can get the length of `Flatten[Table[{a, b, foo}, {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, a}], 1]` using

```
n (n + 1)/2
```

(which is `Sum[1, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, i}]`)

or

```
Length[Subsets[Range[n], {1, 2}]]
```

For `n = 100`:

```
100 101 /2
```

> 5050

```
Length[Subsets[Range[100], {1, 2}]]
```

> 5050

```
table[n_Integer] := Flatten[Table[{a, b, foo}, {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, a}], 1];
Length[table[100]]
```

> 5050

For the second part of the question, using a brute force approach

```
MaximalBy[Reverse/@Subsets[Range[1000],{2}], Length[eaSteps[#]]&]
```

> {{987, 610}}

```
Length[Length[eaSteps[{987, 610}]]] -1
```

> 14

Comment: thank you! so basically the reason I would know its 5050 before I even run the code is if I use `Subsets` right?

Comment: @user130306, that's correct.

Comment: great, thank you again. and for the second part of the question, do the values a = 987, b = 610, n = 14 work and is that the right answer?